# How to stop resizing form at a certain Y axis value in vb

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Here's a pseudo code of what I'd like to do

```
Private Sub frmSearch_Resize(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Resize
    If lvFileListSearch.Location.Y < 204 Then
        frmSearch.lockResizing() 'lockResizing() doesn't exist, I made it up to explain my point
    End If
End Sub
```

Basically, when the user is resizing the form, I want to lock the resizing ability of the form when the Y axis of my listview has reached the constant value.

How would I lock the form?

Thanks

Comment: Use the form.MaximumSize(x, y) and form.MiniumSize(x, y) to restrict form resize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once they try to resize pas 204 do you not want them to be able to resize above 204 or do you just want a minimum? If you want a minimum you can use `form.minimumsize`.

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.form.minimumsize.aspx)

Comment: Why the hell didn't I think about this? Thank you so much.